# asp.net core controller constructor not called at all after replacing autofac with dependencyinjection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, autofac

I have an ASP.Net Core 2.2 application which I originally used Autofac DI which works well. I wanted to try Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection as I read that this is faster than Autofac. Therefore I replace the Autofac Module and type registration with IServiceCollection related functions. However, the result is that the API Controller constructor is never reached at all. No exception is thrown from the xUnit test either. Any advice and insight how to debug this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the root cause. Some of the interfaces and implementations are in a different projects of the solution and it uses "internal" access modifier. Change it to "public" and it works now!